# Vite build gives QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread error

Tags: reactjs, build, vite

I created a react project with vite.

When i run `vite build` command, it gives `QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with QThread` error.

I haven't created any new files in my project. It is just a hello world react project created with vite.

Any idea how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Which node version do you use?

Comment: verison 16.17.1